# Ionic 4 - Application wide background image

Tags: css, ionic4

I am trying to set an application wide background image.

```
@media (min-width: 820px) {
    body {
        --background           : url('https://dummyimage.com/2048x1536/000/fff') no-repeat center center fixed;
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size   : cover;
        background-size        : cover;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 820px) {
    body {
        --background           : url('https://dummyimage.com/1440x1080/000/fff') no-repeat center center fixed;
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size   : cover;
        background-size        : cover;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 576px) {
    body {
        --background           : url('https://dummyimage.com/1024x768/000/fff') no-repeat center center fixed;
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size   : cover;
        background-size        : cover;
    }
}


:host {
    ion-content {
        --background: none;
    }
}
```

This doesn't work. If I replace body with ion-content, it does work but since my pages all have their ion-content, it is not handling transition between pages too well (the background transitions too).

I am a bit lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can achieve what you need by styling  tag inside index.html:

```
<body>

  <app-root></app-root>

  <noscript>Please enable JavaScript to continue using this application.</noscript>
  <style>
    body {
      background: url('https://dummyimage.com/1024x768/000/fff') no-repeat center center fixed;
      -webkit-background-size: cover;
      -moz-background-size: cover;
      background-size: cover;
    }
  </style>
</body>
```

You could use media queries there as well.

Then you need to set ion-content background to none in :root inside theme/variables.scss:

```
:root {
  ion-content {
    --background: none;
  }
```

Comment: That worked. But what it mostly did is make me realize that I made a huge mistake. See how in my .scss I he --background ? Well, that is embarassing.